# To check if ArrayList is empty

Tags: java, android, list, collections, sharedpreferences

I am trying to check if my saved ArrayList is empty or not
when I run the code:

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        String title = intent.getStringExtra(NotePad.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        notes.add(title);
        Log.d("testt", "notes: " + notes);

        if(title != null) {
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = gson.toJson(notes);
            editor.putString(Key, json);
            editor.apply();
            Log.d("ans", "notes: " + notes);
        }

        int t = CheckSharedPreferences();
        Log.d("testt","t: "+t);
}

int CheckSharedPreferences() {
    ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = prefs.getString(Key, null);
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {}.getType();
    test = gson.fromJson(json, type);

    Log.d("testt", "test " + test);

    if(test == null) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

***This method always returns `0` even if the list is empty.***

These is snippet from a log:

```
10-10 01:12:38.254 19365-19365/com.example.quicknote D/testt: notes: [null]
10-10 01:12:38.281 19365-19365/com.example.quicknote D/testt: test[null]
10-10 01:12:38.281 19365-19365/com.example.quicknote D/testt: t: 0
```

Comment: What do you mean by "is empty"? If you have `String s = null` then `s` variable doesn't hold empty string but reference to `null`. To hold empty string you would need to write something along `String s = "";` and since such string exists but *doesn't hold any character* it can be consider as empty. Similarly in your case `if(test == null)` doesn't check if `test` holds empty list, but if it holds `null` *instead* of any list. What you are after is probably `if(test.isEmpty())`.

Comment: I want to check for null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking your logs, it seems

```
test = gson.fromJson(json, type);
```

returns a list with null as first/only element.

you must check these three conditions inside if:

```
if ( test == null || test.isEmpty() || test.get(0) == null ) { return 1;}
```

Comment: But why do we check all three conditions. Is'nt test == null and test.get(0) == null one and the same?

Comment: test == null means the variable referes to null but test.get(0) == null means checking the first element of the list is referring to null .. So both are two different cases .

Answer (score 1):

Try `test.isEmpty()` instead of `test == null`

Answer (score 0):

`test` is never `null`, since you have assigned an object to this variable before: `ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();`

Try this instead: `if(test.isEmpty())`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you may also want to check by the .size() method. The list that isn't empty will have a size more than zero

```
if (test.size()>0){
//execute your code
}
```